# State dict not persisting to checkpoint file for custom callback

Tags: pytorch, callback, pytorch-lightning, checkpoint

I'm attempting to save additional information and metrics from model training in a custom pytorch lightning callback. I've implemented the `load_state_dict` and `state_dict` functions as outlined in the documentation [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.7/extensions/callbacks.html#save-callback-state). However, the information is not being saved to the model's checkpoint file.

I have the following simple custom callback implemented:

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback

class MyCallback(Callback):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.state = {"metric": None}

    def on_train_end(self, trainer: pl.Trainer, pl_module: pl.LightningModule]) -> None:

        # do stuff with trainer and pl_module to get the metric
        updated_metric = ...

        self.state["metric"] = updated_metric

    def load_state_dict(self, state_dict):
        self.state.update(state_dict)

    def state_dict(self):
        return self.state.copy()
```

I initialize and train my trainer with the following callbacks:

```
trainer = pl.trainer(..., callbacks=[EarlyStopping(...), ModelCheckpoint(...), MyCallback(...)])
trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader)
```

After training, direct inspection of the trainer's MyCallback state (`trainer.callbacks[<callback_idx>]["state"]`) indicates that the state has been properly updated with `updated_metric`. However, if I try and load the checkpoint created from training, the callback state does not persist and shows up as `{"metric": None}`. The docs linked above seem to indicate that simply implementing `load_state_dict` and `state_dict` is enough to "persist the state effectively", but I'm not sure if I'm missing something here?

After training, I'm loading the checkpoint with:

```
loaded_state = torch.load(path/to/checkpoint.ckpt)
```

All my callbacks appear in the loaded state's "callbacks" field, but only the ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping callbacks have persistent states. After stepping through MyCallback in my debugger, it seems like `state_dict` is getting called before `on_train_end`. Based on `state_dict`'s doc string, I know that this method gets called when a checkpoint is getting saved, which means the state dict is getting saved before being updated by `on_train_end`. In light of this, I also tried implementing my metric calculation code in the `on_save_checkpoint` hook, but experienced the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.